# Permalink of post redirect to uncategorized category

Tags: permalinks

I have a strange behavior where all my posts get redirected to an url with the uncategorized category, even though a category is set.

In the backend I have a category selected, for example 'teachings', I see the url looking like this http://example.com/teachings/name-of-post, when I click it the url stays good for a second and then redirects to http://example.com/uncategorized/name-of-post

I tried flushing the permalinks by resetting them, but it doesn't work. My permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you set posts with right category before upload post? Can I have temporary user account for testing, view and solve problem. Let's try changing **your default post category** and **delete uncategorized** in wordpress